# How to pass session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to pass a username from login page to master page using session but im getting " Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. My code for login page is,

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Registration where UserName = @username and Password = @password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtLogin.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["name"] = txtLogin.Text.Trim();
        Response.Redirect("ImageSearch.aspx");          
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
    }         
}
```

and for master page code is,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
        Label1.Visible = true;
        string sessionUserName = (string)(Session["name"]);
        Label1.Text = sessionUserName;      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to page lifecycle in Asp.net, Page_Load is always trigger before events.
In your case, Page_Load of your login page is trigger first, the the Page_load of your master page, then the event click. This is why you Session["Name"] is null in your master page.

If you want to update your "Label1.Text" in your master page just after your clicked, you need to update your master page manually.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Registration where UserName = @username and Password = @password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtLogin.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {


            Session["name"] = txtLogin.Text.Trim();
            (Master as SiteMaster).UpdatePage();
            Response.Redirect("ImageSearch.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
        }

    }
```

And in your master page, add a method:

```
    public void UpdatePage()
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        string sessionUserName = (string)(Session["name"]);
        Label1.Text = sessionUserName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The master page load event will get executed before Button click event, so you won't have session value on master page load in this scenario.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx

You can try setting master page label value from Button click event, itself -

```
this.Master.Label11.Text = txtLogin.Text.Trim();
```